# WP - Lightbox does not work on Owl Carousel's first item

Tags: wordpress, lightbox, owl-carousel, visual-composer

In below page, I have built a gallery slider with Visual Composer. It's using Owl Carousel library.

When I enable the Lightbox option, it's not working on the first image, most of the time.

You will understand me after looking at the URL: http://www.turnabakir.com/test/index.php/portfolio-item/kayik-sahan/

Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

I got the same problem between the OwlCarousel and GLightbox. Because I don't want to disable the loop option I tried to re-initializing the Glightbox after the OwlCarousel calling like this:

```
$("#carouselboxid").owlCarousel({});

const myLightbox = GLightbox({
  selector: ".elemclass-lightbox"
});
```

Answer (score 0):

I just disabled looping attribute of OwlCarousel and the problem is solved. It was something related to looping. My guess is when Owl was cloning items one after another, binding of Lightbox was affected. It is not the answer of my question, but my problem is solved, so topic can be closed.